# how to display in messagebox a C function from C# with a WCHAR*

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, interop, dllimport

I'm building a C# application that loads a C++ library.
I call functions from that C++ DLL. I use below function to display input string.

c++ dll:

```
wchar_t* Test_EchoString( wchar_t *InputStr )
{
String HWStr = String( InputStr );  

return HWStr.c_str();
}
```

c# code:

```
[DllImport("testDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern int  _Test_EchoString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string s);

private void echo_string_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string upn = "aaaaa";
    _Test_EchoString(upn);

    MessageBox.Show(_Test_EchoString(upn).ToString());    
}
```

I get in messagebox number 18666252 but i want to get a string from `_Test_EchoString()`.

Comment: Wait... wouldn't HWStr get destroyed when it goes out of scope and, in consequence, the pointer returned by HWStr.c_str() become invalid?

Comment: `_Test_EchoString` returns an integer (`public static extern int  _Test_EchoString`). int.ToString returns the string representation of the number

Comment: What is `String` in `wchar_t* Test_EchoString( wchar_t *InputStr )` method? Is it `std::wstring`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pair of problems in your code:

in your C# you defined `_Test_EchoString` as `public static extern int  _Test_EchoString`, so when you execute it, the returned value will be the address of the first character of the string `HWStr.c_str()`.
And here it shows another problem, as anderas said, you are returning an invalid pointer, because `HWStr.c_str()` returns the pointer to the current value of the `std::wstring` object, so it is valid as long that the `wstring` is valid, so when the method `Test_EchoString` ends its execution it is no more valid(because `HWStr` is destroyed).

There are different ways to fix this problems, I'm going to show you two of these:

**1)** The first is to allocate the memory you want to return in the Heap and free it later with another call:

```
static wchar_t *Test_EchoStringResult;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) const wchar_t * Test_EchoStringNew(const wchar_t *InputStr)
{
    std::wstring HWStr(InputStr);
    HWStr += L" something";
    Test_EchoStringResult = new wchar_t[HWStr.length() + sizeof(wchar_t)];
    HWStr.copy(Test_EchoStringResult, HWStr.length());
    Test_EchoStringResult[HWStr.length()] = L'\0';
    return Test_EchoStringResult;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Test_EchoStringDelete()
{
    delete[] Test_EchoStringResult;
}
```

And this is the usage in C#:

```
[DllImport("testDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr Test_EchoStringNew(string foo);

[DllImport("testDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void Test_EchoStringDelete();

public void foo()
{
    string result = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(Test_EchoStringNew("test"));
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    Test_EchoStringDelete();
}
```

To me, this looks pretty ugly, so I'd prefer to use another pattern

**2)** Passing a callback to the C method and pass to this method `HWStr.c_str()` when `HWStr` is still valid:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Test_EchoString(const wchar_t *InputStr, void (*callback)(const wchar_t*))
{
    std::wstring HWStr(InputStr);
    HWStr += L" something";
    callback(HWStr.c_str());
}
```

And here is the C# usage:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate void myCallback(string toShow);

[DllImport("testDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void Test_EchoString(string foo, myCallback callback);

public void foo()
{
    Test_EchoString("test", callback);
}

void callback(string toShow)
{
    MessageBox.Show(toShow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion